# What does Thread Local Objects mean in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am reading the Flask documentation (specifically, the [*Foreword for Experienced Programmers* chapter](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/advanced_foreword/)) and I read this -

> One of the design decisions in Flask was that simple tasks should be simple; they should not take a lot of code and yet they should not limit you. Because of that, Flask has few design choices that some people might find surprising or unorthodox. For example, Flask uses thread-local objects internally so that you don’t have to pass objects around from function to function within a request in order to stay threadsafe. This approach is convenient, but requires a valid request context for dependency injection or when attempting to reuse code which uses a value pegged to the request. The Flask project is honest about thread-locals, does not hide them, and calls out in the code and documentation where they are used.

What does this mean? Specifically the following questions -

- What are thread local objects? How and when they are used and what purpose do they solve?
- How using thread-local objects internally ensure thread safety and how does passing objects to function result in not-thread-safe?
- What is the meaning of a valid request context in this case?

Answer (score 34):

A thread-local object is an object that is stored in a dedicated structure, tied to the current thread id. If you ask this structure for the object, it'll use the current thread identifier to give you data unique to the current thread. See [`threading.local`](https://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.local). You can get more detail still by entering `import _threading_local; help(_threading_local)` into your Python interactive interpreter.

This means that whenever you use `current_app`, `g` or `requests` you get a data structure that is safe to use in your thread (or process, or eventlet), without you having to worry about locking and other concurrency issues.

In normal operation, Flask handles incoming WSGI requests; for each such request a request context is created for you; this is represented by the `g` and `request` objects. If you are trying to use any of your views *without* an incoming request (say, in your tests), then the `request` object will not work and complain that there is no valid request context. Flask provides you with the tools to produce such a context on demand in that case. See the [*Faking Resources and Context* documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/testing/#faking-resources-and-context), as well as the [*Request Context*](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/reqcontext/) chapter.

Comment: When user enters flask URL in the browser, and the request hits the flask server, then does the flask server spin up a new process or a new thread for each URL request? And does each process/thread has the request context containing the g, current_app and request object from the user's previous requests - which are stored on the server and deciphered based on the token sent by the user request?

Comment: @variable: how concurrency is handled is up to the WSGI container server, not Flask itself, e.g. if you used Gunicorn you can [configure the number of processes and threads](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#worker-processes) it'll use. Each request has a *new* `current_app` and `request` object. Other code, like the [Flask `Session` API](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#sessions) build on top of that to do things like loading data based on tokens. That's entirely separate.

Comment: I believe Flask also calls `current_app` and `request` [context locals](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/#purpose-of-the-context), since they are destroyed after every request on a single thread (rather than thread locals, which implies having the same lifetime as the thread).

Comment: @kennysong yes, but the documentation for that feature explicitly references the thread-local concept, and this question is asking about that concept. My answer addresses the question asked, I'm not naming the Flask context locals here.